# What does 'I lose myself in him' mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms

The following dialogue is from Arrow:

> I lose myself in him.

I guess it's supposed to be a romantic line. But what does this actually mean? Does this mean the person forgets his/her own identity when she is around the character she is talking about ?

Comment: Figuratively, it could mean that; see [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lose-in).

Comment: Also, you can see [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lose+oneself+in).

Comment: A detailed quote (identifying the source) may help.

Comment: Also [here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/lose-yourself-in-something).

Answer (score 2):

When used romantically, it means that there are no other thoughts in the speakers mind when they are thinking about or are around "him".

It implies that "him" becomes all consuming, and possibly rational thought disappears, thus the saying

> Love is blind.

when nothing else can be "seen".

Comment: I don't know if "love is blind" is related - to me that means you don't see the other person's flaws because of how you fee about theml. You can "lose yourself" in music, or in the moment; it's not just for a relationship between people. The definition at http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lose+oneself+in talks about "being absorbed".

Answer (score 2):

[Lose oneself](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/lose-oneself) has several meanings as follows:

> 1. to lose one's way; go astray; become bewildered
> 2. to become absorbed
> 3. to disappear from view or notice

No. 2 definition applies to the sentence and it means

> I am so absorbed in him that I can't think about other people or things.

Related question on English Language Learners:

[What does “Lose Yourself” mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51241/what-does-lose-yourself-mean)